# Where to find a User Story draft?

Tags: azure-devops

When creating a new User Story and we chose to close it, we get 3 options "Cancel", "Discard" or "Save changes".

By choosing the option to "Save changes" one would expect a draft version of the ticket to be created and saved, but where is it?

Steps to reproduce the case in question:

1. On the Backlog, choose an existing well created and saved Feature to be used as parent
2. Do the action of creating a children User Story:
3. Fill in some text for the description of the ticket, but do not complete the action, do not fill all required fields, for example the title
4. Click to close the ticket to get the prompt to choose: "Cancel", "Discard" or "save changes"
5. Choose to save changes.

Notice how now the popup for the new ticket is closed without any issue.
Where is it located? How do you get back the form you saved? Where is it saved?

I tried looking for any "newest tickets" feature in azure dev ops. Cant find such.

Tried looking for any ticket related to the parent I chose. Nothing.

I tried creating a new ticket hoping for an option to load old saved values. Nop.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your reproduced steps on my side, when you close the ticket(even you choose `save changes`), `actually the user story is NOT created`. Hence, you cannot find it on your project. There is no draft user story in devops.

[image]

If you enable `network trace`(press F12 on browser) , you can see there's no work item creation record.

[image]

In addition, you can also go to boards -> Work items -> My activity/ or Rencently recreated page to confirm.

[image]